# Prepositional/infinitive phrase connectors

Tags: grammar

When prepositional /infinitive phrases are used as sentence connectors, ie they come at the beginning of a sentence, what is their status in the sentence? Are they mere connectors and not a part of the sentence or they also are integral part of the sentence they introduce?

Example:

- He is a hardworking man. Apart from this, he is also very diligent.

Here is "apart from this" only a connector or also an integral part of the sentence "he is also very diligent?

Similarly,

- He wants to be rich. To achieve his objective, he is working very hard.

Here, is "To achieve his objective" only a connector or also an integral part of the sentence "he is working very hard", acting as an adverbial?

Comment: That particular infinitive --  _to achieve his objective_ --  is a purpose infinitive, which can be tested by adding _in order_ before _to_ without changing the meaning. _Apart from this_ has the same structure and function as _in addition,   nevertheless, whatever else you may say about him,_ and millions of other phrases. Nothing to see here, folks.

Comment: 'Apart from this' and 'also' are hard to justify as both being necessary here.  And 'diligent' and 'hardworking'? // 'An integral part of the sentence' is probably meant in a syntactic sense. Obviously 'Apart from this' and 'To achieve his objective' are parentheticals, [longer] adjuncts which may be deleted to leave meaningful independent ('matrix') clauses. But they often carry significant semantic weight (ie you lose meaning if you don't include them), and semantically a sentence 'expresses a **complete** thought'. Now we just have to well-define 'complete'.

Answer (score 1):

Phrases such as "apart from this" or "for this purpose" work as **sentence modifiers**. Within a larger text, they function as linkers between sentences and make for the cohesion of the text.

Comment: Thanks Gustavson for your reply. When you say they work as"sentence modifiers".I feel unlike conjunctive adverbs which modifies the complete clause of which it is part,  the prepositional /infinitive connectors are used at the beginning of a sentence only for emphasis and they act as adverbial modifying the main verb of the clause of which they are part